# How to see logs for failure reason when creating VM

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I am creating an Azure VM using the below PowerShell script

```
$username = 'xxxxxxx'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxxxxx&Cx4cA' -AsPlainText -Force
$WindowsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "1-83eb7c26-playground-sandbox" `
    -Name "aznewvm23" `
    -Location 'eastus' `
    -VirtualNetworkName "mynewazvm23" `
    -SubnetName "default" `
    -SecurityGroupName "mynewvmNSG23" `
    -PublicIpAddressName "mypublicip23" `
    -Credential $WindowsCred `
    -OpenPorts 80,3389 `
    -AsJob
```

And when I see job status using `Get-Job` it's getting failed.

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Long Running O… AzureLongRunni… Failed        True            localhost            New-AzVM
```

I want to see the failure reason, How can I get job logs using PowerShell?

```
PS az204_prep> New-AzVM `
>>     -ResourceGroupName 'psdemo-rg' `
>>     -Name 'psdemo-win-az4' `
>>     -Image 'Win2019Datacenter'`
>>     -Credential $WindowsCred `
>>     -OpenPorts 3389 `
>>     -AsJob


Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Long Running O… AzureLongRunni… Running       True            localhost            New-AzVM

PS az204_prep> Get-Job


Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Long Running O… AzureLongRunni… Failed        True            localhost            New-AzVM

PS az204_prep> (Get-Job 1).JobStateInfo.State

Failed
PS az204_prep> (Get-Job 1).JobStateInfo.Reason

PS az204_prep>
```

Comment: Can you Please try referring this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-job?view=powershell-7.1#example-9--investigate-a-failed-job?

Comment: Tried with `(Get-Job 1).JobStateInfo.Reason` and not getting any info logs as the response. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Yes, its same for me as well, but if i run Get-Job | Format-List -Property *, i can get debug details .

Comment: I think you have to remove -As job for it to success.

Comment: No, I think that's not the reason. Thank you @AnsumanBal-MT.

Comment: i tested it without as job it got succeded and its created in the resource group as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Get the Job Details, You can use Get-Job | Format-List -Property * , to get the Full details of the Job performed in Powershell.

[image]

---

The Operation is failing as you are creating a VM with Default Configuration and default command , So you don't have to use -As Job there. Please remove -As Job and it will successfully get created.

**I tested it on my environment using the same command you are using (removing -As Job):**

```
$username = 'xxxxxxx'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxxxxx&Cx4cA' -AsPlainText -Force
$WindowsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName 'myresourcegroupname' -Name 'psdemo-win-az4' -Image 'Win2019Datacenter' -Credential $WindowsCred -OpenPorts 443
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[New-AzVM (Az.Compute) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azvm?view=azps-6.4.0)

---

**Creating with -As Job :**

```
$VMLocalAdminUser = "LocalAdminUser"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$LocationName = "westus"
$ResourceGroupName = "myresourcegroup"
$ComputerName = "mycomputername"
$VMName = "MYVMName"
$VMSize = "Standard_DS3"

$NetworkName = "Myvnet"
$NICName = "MyNIC"
$SubnetName = "MySubnet"
$SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
$VnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"

$SingleSubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName -AddressPrefix $SubnetAddressPrefix
$Vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $NetworkName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -AddressPrefix $VnetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SingleSubnet
$NIC = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $NICName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -SubnetId $Vnet.Subnets[0].Id

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword);

$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Windows -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $NIC.Id
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsServer' -Offer 'WindowsServer' -Skus '2012-R2-Datacenter' -Version latest

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose -AsJob
```

I failed it by not satisfying the password Criteria, So, when I check the error message I can see why it failed.

[image]

After I change the Password satisfying the criteria the job succeeds.

[image]

**In Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Great Answer!! Thank you.